# Access any type of file name using MIME

Tags: android, file, mime-types

We have get a `File Extension` and `MIME Type`. It's working fine for only the normal file. Some Files does not access. For example `Hello.pdf` working fine and `JSP Quick Reference.pdf` not working. Because this file contains `space`. How do access this files using `MIME`.
MimeTypeMap map = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();

String ext = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(file.getName());
Log.e("Extension : " + ext + "","Extension : " + ext + "");
// Result `Extension :`

String type = map.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
Log.e("Extension Type : " + type + "","Extension Type : " + type + "");
// Result `Extension Type : null`

How do access `special characters` and `space` files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might have to use regular expressions to filter out files with special characters!

Comment: @Dya Now it's working fine. Is it possible to `MIME`. Thanks.